# Initialize HashMap with an array of items?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have the result of a long processing. I don't want to pass it directly to a HashMap and do some more computation. I want to save it and then reuse everytime.

My array of values looks like this:

```
{0=0, 1=15, 2=70, 3=90, 4=90, 5=71, 6=11, 7=1, 8=61, 9=99, 10=100, 11=100, 12=100, 13=66, 14=29, 15=98, 17=100, 16=100, 19=100, 18=100, 21=62, 20=90, 23=100, 22=100, 25=100, 24=100, 27=91, 26=100, 29=100, 28=68, 31=100, 30=100, 34=83, 35=55, 32=100, 33=100, 38=100, 39=100, 36=100, 37=100, 42=10, 43=90, 40=99, 41=33, 46=99, 47=40, 44=100, 45=100, 48=2}
```

Is there a way to initialize a new HashMap by passing these values? Maybe something like initializing a simple array:

```
float[] list={1,2,3};
```

Comment: Are the keys really consecutive integers?

Comment: What's the type of the values in the array? What should be the type of the keys and values of the map?

Comment: @BorisStrandjev yes, they are the content of a previous HashMap println'ed

Comment: @JBNizet HashMap<Integer,Integer>

Comment: I don't understand your question. You already have a HashMap, but want to create another one? Do you want to clone the original map?

Comment: @Andrew I mean are you sure the keys will always be every value in integer interval like in your case [0, 48], and if so why do you need hash map? Integer array is doing such kind of mapping.

Comment: Its much easier to create the array from a Map than the other way around. But you can do either.  You can also save a HashMap "and reuse everytime"  It appears all your keys are small continuous numbers. You could just use a List or an array.  You may not need a Map at all.

Comment: @JBNizet I have the values of a previous HashMap and I copied it. Now I want to start with the values in a new HashMap and not do the processing to get them again.

Comment: An `int[]` is even simpler than an `Integer[]` or `HashMap<Integer, Integer>` If you want a collection, you can use TIntArrayList.

Comment: @Andrew it sounds like you don't actually have an array, even though that could be the best solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the problem you put infront of us the best solution will be:

```
int [] map =
  {0, 15, 70, 90, 90, 71, 11, 1, 61, 99, 100, 100, 100, 66, 29, 98, 100, 100, 
   100, 100, 90, 62, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 91, 68, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100,
   83, 55, 100, 100, 100, 100, 99, 33, 10, 90, 100, 100, 99, 40, 2};
```

This is a kind of map after all - it maps an index to the corresponding value. However, if your keys are not that specific you can do something like:

```
int [][] initializer =
    {{0, 0}, {1, 15}, {2, 70}, {3, 90}, {4, 90}, {5, 71}, {6, 11}, {7, 1}, {8, 61},
     {9, 99}, {10, 100}, {11, 100}, {12, 100}, {13, 66}, {14, 29}, {15, 98},
     {17, 100}, {16, 100}, {19, 100}, {18, 100}, {21, 62}, {20, 90}, {23, 100},
     {22, 100}, {25, 100}, {24, 100}, {27, 91}, {26, 100}, {29, 100}, {28, 68},
     {31, 100}, {30, 100}, {34, 83}, {35, 55}, {32, 100}, {33, 100}, {38, 100},
     {39, 100}, {36, 100}, {37, 100}, {42, 10}, {43, 90}, {40, 99}, {41, 33},
     {46, 99}, {47, 40}, {44, 100}, {45, 100}, {48, 2}};
Map<Integer, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer> ();
for (int i = 0; i < initializer.length; i++) {
    myMap.put(initializer[i][0], initializer[i][1]);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

the only way to initialize a `HashMap` with values is by using the `put()` method multiple times after you create the object.  This is because the the `HashMap` needs to do the hashing mechanism to properly order the objects in the map to achieve the performance that it guarantees.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very confusing. It what you want is to copy the contents of a Map to another Map, use the [putAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putAll%28java.util.Map%29) method.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> newMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
newMap.putAll(oldMap);
```

or the copy constructor directly:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> newMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(oldMap);
```

Comment: or use the constructor: `HashMap(Map<? extends K,? extends V> m)` :)

Comment: What data type is oldMap?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't instantiate a Hashmap as easily as an array.

What you can do, is write an utitlity method and use that to instantiate a map:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> createMap(Integer[] array) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        map.put(i, array[i]);
    }
    return map;
}
```